# Get values from a HTML array with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

My goal is to get values from a specific row in a HTML array and put them into forms, like so :

```
$("#tableID tr").click(function()
{
    var mh = $(this).closest("tr");
    document.getElementById("Catégorie").value= mh.find("td:first").text();
}
```

This one above works perfectly : I get the first value of a row and the appropriate form is filled with it.
How can I do the same with the other values of the row ? I already tried several methods with several key-words, but I'm certainly doing it wrong... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where to fill the retrieved value?

Comment: use `mh.find("td:eq(0)").text(),mh.find("td:eq(1)").text();`  and so on up to last td  . index start form `0`

Answer (score 1):

use below code using **[each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**

```
 mh.find("td").each(function(index){
    // index will return index of td
   // $(this).text()  return text of each td
   if(index == 0){
     $("#Catégorie").val($(this).text());
   }
 });
```

or you can use [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to text of td base on index

```
$("#Catégorie").val(mh.find("td:eq(0)").text());
$("#othervalue").val(mh.find("td:eq(1)").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to iterate through all tds of current row and get the `text` in them. Using get will return you the array but to assign to Catégorie.value you need a string. To get string from array you can use `join()` as shown in given example code.

```
document.getElementById("Catégorie").value= mh.find("td").map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join('');
```

If you want to separate those values of `td` you can pass that character to `join` for instead comma `','`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#tableID tr").click(function()
{
    var mh = $(this).closest("tr");
      mh.find('td').each(function(){
      document.getElementById("Catégorie").value= this.text();
    }
}
```

Using *each()* function you can loop the element of a selection

Comment: what is  `thi.text();`  ??